# Postgresql paging perfomance for JOIN query

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-optimization

I have two tables:

`products` ~ 20mln records

`tags` ~35mln records

And have perfomance problem with such queries:

```
SELECT products.name 
FROM products 
INNER JOIN tags ON tags.product_id=products.id
WHERE 
  products.categoryid IN (1,2,3..) AND
  tags.id = 3 
ORDER BY products.position 
LIMIT 64 OFFSET 0;
```

When OFFSET is small all is good. When OFFSET is about >1000 query executes 10-80 seconds.

Already have index for `ORDER BY position` (products table) and `product_id, id` (tags table).

```
    (OFFSET=100)
    Limit  (cost=85705.10..147411.97 rows=72 width=667) (actual time=1623.013..2334.542 rows=72 loops=1)
          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.13..67736996.34 rows=79036 width=667) (actual time=4.898..2334.493 rows=172 loops=1)
                ->  Index Scan using items_sorting_index on products  (cost=0.56..61905349.96 rows=1513209 width=667) (actual time=0.083..2188.800 rows=17547 loops=1)
                      Filter: (categoryid = ANY ('{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}'::bigint[]))
                      Rows Removed by Filter: 638658
                ->  Index Only Scan using index_tags_on_product_id_and_tag_id on tags  (cost=0.56..3.84 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=0 loops=17547)
                      Index Cond: ((product_id = products.id) AND (id = 3))
                      Heap Fetches: 28
        Planning time: 1.345 ms
        Execution time: 2334.608 ms
```

`tags.id` can be different in query and the result elements are different for different tags, so I think I can't use such methods as cursor-field.

How can I optimize this query?

Comment: Your stats look a bit off (expected `rows=1513209` vs actual `rows=17547` in the product table). You might want to run an `ANALYZE` on both tables first. Another thing you could try is make the `items_sorting_index` index cover the `name` column (see [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html)).

Comment: @Marth the stats are off because the "expected" rows doesn't take the LIMIT into account, while the actual rows does.

Comment: I don't understand your objection to a cursor.  Or is a  "cursor-field" something different than a cursor?

Comment: @jjanes add field to table which will help to count page position (like http://allyouneedisbackend.com/blog/2017/09/24/the-sql-i-love-part-1-scanning-large-table/). It is not for my problem

Comment: key-set pagination should work fine as long as people are actually stepping through the data, rather than wanting to jump to page 50 without first seeing 1-49.  If position is not unique, you would need to add a tie breaker into the ORDER BY.

Comment: I can’t use key pagination. I work with two tables, and based in tags.id value the result number of pages is different for all tags.

Comment: Why does that mean you can't use key-set pagination?  If people are changing the specified value to which tags.id is compared between paging requests, then they aren't paging, they are doing something else.

Comment: Can you please provide example how I can use key-set pagination for such JOIN query?

Answer (score 1):

You can decrease data set by filer tags table before join like:

```
SELECT products.name 
FROM products 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT id FROM tags WHERE tags.id = 3
) tags ON tags.product_id=products.id
WHERE 
  products.categoryid IN (1,2,3..)
ORDER BY products.position 
LIMIT 64 OFFSET 0;
```

or filter two tables separately and join results:

```
SELECT products.name 
FROM (
  SELECT name, position FROM products WHERE products.categoryid IN (1,2,3..)
) products 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT id FROM tags WHERE tags.id = 3
) tags ON tags.product_id=products.id
ORDER BY products.position 
LIMIT 64 OFFSET 0;
```

Comment: Если мы делаем JOIN двух таблиц, записи сравниваются последовательно из подходящих по критериям или создаются два больших набора, которые объединяются по условию? Во втором вашем примере если у меня будет миллионы записей с tags.id = 3, то не будет ли это тяжело для БД создать такой dataset для последующего JOIN?

Comment: Уважаемый @НиколайАгеев, Please write your comment in English, so all SO users can read and collaborate. About my suggestion, the best way to test it is test on your dataset. Just run the query and comment here is it helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can use keyset pagination just fine. The initial query would be:

```
SELECT products.name, products.position, products.id
FROM products 
INNER JOIN tags ON tags.product_id=products.id
WHERE 
  products.categoryid IN (1,2,3..) AND
  tags.id = 3 
ORDER BY products.position, products.id
LIMIT 64;
```

and the following query would be

```
SELECT products.name, products.position, products.id
FROM products 
INNER JOIN tags ON tags.product_id=products.id
WHERE 
  products.categoryid IN (1,2,3..) AND
  tags.id = 3
  AND (products.position, products.id) > ($1, $2)
ORDER BY products.position, products.id
LIMIT 64;
```

Where `$1` and `$2` are the last values returned by the preceeding query.

An index on `products (products.position, products.id)` makes the query fast.

Comment: And what if position is boolean field? Or if I need to use products.stock (true/false). The result will not be sorted by ascending

Comment: What `boolean` field? There is nothing like that in your question. But it is easy to add more columns to the result or the `ORDER BY` clause.